# MathJax not displayed properly

Tags: bug, formatting, mathjax

Lately I've been seeing expressions rendered by MathJax not displayed properly: they all have a vertical bar at the end. See image below. This occurs for both inline and display math expressions, in the post as well as in comments.

[image]

This seems to be unique to Econ.SE site. Math.SE doesn't seem to suffer from this issue:

[image]

Is this just me? I'm using Version 48.0.2564.82 of Chrome.

Comment: I did not experience the problem with Chrome 47.something and neither after updating to 48.0.2564.97.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue specific to Chrome 48 (possibly, not on every OS). It has been [reported and fixed in MathJax 2.6.0](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1300) which was [released recently](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-6-now-available/).

It's possible you may have an older version of MathJax cached in your browser. Check the version that is displayed by right-clicking an equation and selecting "about MathJax".

You wouldn't see this on Math.SE because Math is on the beta channel of MathJax, unlike other SE sites. (It loads the script from beta.mathjax.org)

Comment: Thanks! My MathJax is v2.5.3. That's why.